# Is there a way to only have one AWS APIGateway request to get output of AWS StepFunction?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I'm looking for a best practice to setup a AWS Workflow in AWS CDK including StepFunctions and ApiGateway.

I have a working AWS StepFunction that I can call over an AWS APIGateway endpoint. Unfortunately I have to run first a `POST` request to get an `'executionId'` which I then have to call within a `GET` in order to get the output of my StateFunction.

Is there a way that I only have to call 1 request? The `'executionId'` isn't instant callable, I have to build in a small delay in my frontend and this is definitly not a best practice.

Comment: Unlikely, step functions are *basically* asynchronous - how long will your step functions run?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Not more than a few seconds. If I try it out over Postman the copy pasting of the executionId is enough time so that I'll receive a proper response and not "no data".

Comment: In theory you could build another lambda that starts the step function, gets its id and then polls for the execution to complete and only then returns that data to the gateway. Not pretty but I doubt API Gateway has anything built-in for this. The main reason for that is that step functions are likely to take quite some time, maybe with human interaction, call external APIs, wait for their progress, etc. and with all that reach the 29s integration timeout that API Gateway imposes. You could ask yourself why you have a step function in the first place but that is a different topic.

Comment: I didn't know about the 29s timeout! Interesting... How would you set up the automated communication/exchange between different Lambdas and DynamoDBs? SNS?

Comment: That is too broad to answer and I doubt you can give enough technical and business details for me to decide wether it makes sense to have it as a step function or a regular lambda (especially on SO), sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem by using a WebSocket to be able to listen to changes/answers